# Grid State is not being saved when more than once instance used

Tags: extjs, extjs4

If I have more than one instance of a Grid I have numerous problems. One problem is that the saving of state (ie. sorting, filter widths etc.), doesn't work properly. Saving of state is reset when I navigate to *another* instance of the same Grid. However if I am on the page with just one grid, I can click on refresh, and change things about, and everything saves OK. Its just when i navigate to a screen with another instance of my grid.

Yes, I am setting a different **stateId** for the two instances, and I am making a call to **Ext.state.Manager** at the start of the application :

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));
```

The creation of an instance looks like this :

```
this.packageGrid = Ext.create('js.grid.PackageGrid', {
    stateId: 'CompletePackageGrid', //for my other instance I obviously use a different string here
    width: 979,
    height: 400,

});
```

And my Grid code looks like this :

```
Ext.define('js.grid.PackageStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    model: 'js.model.Package',
    remoteFilter : false,
    remoteSort: false
});


var createColumns = function () {

    var columns = [{
        dataIndex: 'id',
        text: 'ID',
        width: 80,
        filter: {
            type: 'int'
        }
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'packageName',
        text: 'Name of Packet',
        width: 300,
        filter: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    }, {
    }];

    return columns;
};



Ext.define('js.grid.PackageGrid', {

    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    title: '',
    multiSelect: true,
    autoExpandColumn: 'name',
    loadMask: true,
    stateful: true, //*******STATEFUL!!!!

    filterable: true,

    initComponent : function (){

        this.columns = createColumns();

        this.initialConfig.columns = this.columns;

        this.store = new js.grid.PackageStore();

        this.plugins = {
            ptype: 'bufferedrenderer',
            trailingBufferZone: 20,  // Keep 20 rows rendered in the table behind scroll
            leadingBufferZone: 50   // Keep 50 rows rendered in the table ahead of scroll
        };

        this.viewConfig = {
            stripeRows: true,
            enableTextSelection: true
        };

        this.features = {
            ftype: 'filters',
            encode: false,
            local: true
        };

        this.callParent();
    }

});
```

I have tried to put as much code into my **initComponent** method, so there is less risk of objects being shared.

How does the code for my Grid look? Is there anything there that would explain this problem?

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is to fix up your code. At a glance, there's a bunch of obvious problems with it:
1) width/height should be numeric, not string values.
2) A layout is redundant on a grid.
3) A flex is redundant when you specify width/height.
4) `remoteFiler` typo.
5) Defining a class that has a method to pull in the columns in some unrelated global function.
6) No `autoExpandColumn` config exists.
7) `var me = this;` without ever using it.

None of these relate to your question, however it's indicative that perhaps you're not fully understanding some of the code you're writing.

Comment: updated with points 1,2,3,4,7. Updated my question, but problem still there though. Still looking at 5,6. I think the problem lies with point 5. Somehow the columns are getting shared or overwritten because I am using a global variable here. thanks for your help so far :)